How is it possible to create bootable USB purely by using dd command and .iso file?
To my understanding, BIOS should boot from USB the same way as it does from HDD.
On the contrary, bootable CD/DVD must comply to El Torito specification which is some add-on to ISO 9660 filesystem used on CD's/DVD's.
ISO image with Linux distro is prepared to be used with CD/DVD so the ISO 9660 filesystem is involved.
Now if i just dd the .iso image to USB as in this tutorial
then how is it possible BIOS will be able to boot from that USB?
I expect that when BIOS boots from USB it doesn't understand ISO 9660 filesystem and proceeds in the same way as when it boots from HDD. So how it can work? Is any kind of trick involved?

Legacy boot or EFI boot?

See "hybrid ISO" (basically ISO with an MBR, which means with a partition table too).

@user10489: BIOS so legacy

@TomYan: Thanks, that could be that "trick".

It is possible because the ISO is so called Hybrid ISO. Thanks @TomYan.
Bellow is more information that explains why it is possible, basically there is unused space at the beginning that can be used for arbitrary data (making the USB recognizable as bootable by BIOS in my case).
https://wiki.osdev.org/ISO_9660

An ISO 9660 filesystem begins by 32 KiB which may be used for
arbitrary data. This is often used to store boot information for the
case that the ISO 9660 filesystem is not stored on optical media, but
rather on a hard-disk-like device, e.g. on a USB stick.
So be prepared to find at that location a Master Boot Record (MBR, for
BIOS), a GUID Partition Table (GPT, for EFI), or an Apple Partition
Map (APM).


When booting in standard BIOS, it looks for the MBR on the USB drive.  The BIOS reads the MBR, which points it to the bootloader.
The bootloader is what reads the filesystem (ISO 9660, EXT4, FAT32, etc.) booting the OS kernel.
UEFI uses a partition called the EFI System Partition, the ESP, formatted to FAT32. It contains EFI executables, .efi files, and the bootloader. The UEFI firmware reads the .efi from the ESP.  Like with standard BIOS, the bootloader will load the OS.

Bootable USB drives with dd can work for some .iso files, but for Windows,  you'll run into issues. Windows .iso partition layout isn't compatible with the way dd writes the image to the USB drive.
If what you're after is Windows related, you want to use woeusb.

How is any of what I've said not related?I believe that my facetious comment IS the answer to the title.
Clone:
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=~/disk_image.img bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress

Restore:
sudo dd if=~/disk_image.img of=/dev/sdb bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress 


Please at least remove the last part of your answer. Let alone filesystem-aware cloning is utterly irrelevant to the question, writing an ext4 partition/filesystem image to a (partitionless) drive is exactly a case in which it will NOT be bootable. (Even the other parts of your answer is merely remotely relevant / on point.)

@TomYan It's a partition image.  It will boot because it's not using an MBR, dd will lay the original partition block for block, including GRUB.  This ain't windows, my friend.

GRUB doesn't even embed boot code in any formatted partition. It places its boot code in the MBR and the post-MBR gap (msdos partition table) or BIOS boot partition (GPT). The remaining file-based parts of it (namely the modules and grub.cfg, etc.) that resides in /boot will be useless even if the cloned filesystem consists of /boot, because the BIOS would only "look at" the MBR (LBA 0) for boot code. (And while technically you can write an ext4 DXE for UEFI firmware, I'm pretty sure no firmware in the market would have that, and no distro will use an ext4 partition as the ESP either.)

While I faintly remember syslinux does / can do something similar to Windows (namely having "VBR boot code" embedded in a formatted partition), it would also require an MBR with corresponding boot code that "chainloads" it.

@TomYan  CLONE: sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=~/disk_image.img bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress RESTORE: sudo dd if=~/disk_image.img of=/dev/sdb bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress

Please don't waste our time. I know what cloning is better than you do. What you wrote and removed was cloning a partition to a (partitionless) drive. It could only be hilarious for you to "shove" the comment above "to my face". And again, it's irrelevant to the question, period.

Don't go implying it can't be done just because partclone doesn't. Because dd will clone an entire disk, including the bootloader, partition table, and all partitions.

Windows .iso partition layout FYI, the very reason it won't be bootable when dded is exactly because Windows ISOs you downloaded on a Microsoft website (not talking about media creator) are filesystem images (no MBR, no partitions). It's just that the filesystem type is UDF, not ext4. (I mean, if at least you have written something like this, then your answer would be a bit more informative and/or have a bit more relevance to the question.)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
